# How to create a regular expression to validate zip- and postal codes?

Tags: regex

I need a  a regular expression to validate Zipcode or postcode - it must be 8 characters 
alphanumeric field i.e allow A-Z, a-z, or 0-9.

Thanks.

Comment: @dylan7 - hello. Try to update your question and explain what you're trying to accept. You say they "don't work" - please explain how, and how are you testing them.

Answer (score 9):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

This will also work, but usually allows underscores: `^\w{8}$`

### Update:

To allow free spaces within the string (for simplicity, this allows extra spaces on the end of the string, but not the beginning):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]\s*){8}$
```

This allows free spaces, hyphens and (back)?slashed, which are common in zip codes:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][\s\\/-]*){8}$
```

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$ this works but does not allow spaces . How can I allow for spaces ???? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant, because not all number patterns that satisfy a zip code format are valid zip codes.

Comment: But: strings that don't match this patters are **definitely not zip codes**. You'll may have to verify that in some point, but it is wise to validate the format before you make an expensive query against a list of all real zip-codes...

Comment: none of the reg expression seems to work - not sure , the spec says allow for alphanumeric characters which includes spaces but not special cahracters

Answer (score 0):

I would try to validate zip/postal codes in conjunction with the country code - if your validation framework supports this kind of custom validation. It's going to lead to more accurate validation especially if many of your customers are from a particular country.

For instance i check for country code first and if it is US I can be more specific :

```
   if (countryCode == "US") {

      regex = "^\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?$";    // trim string first
   }
   else {

       // see other answers!
   }
```

(of course this applies to any country, such as UK where postal codes are a fixed format)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in validating addresses around the world, check out http://intlmailaddress.com.  It has postal address formats, postal code formats and phone formats from 246 countries.  Region names, (like state, province, emirate, sheng, etc.)